# Calculating the Imaginary part of an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have started using Mathematica recently. I have encountered some difficulty calculating the imaginary part of an equation. I am trying to simulate X-ray reflectivity curves using Fresnel formulas that have an imaginary part. I have uploaded the equations. Can someone please help with the calculation of the imaginary parts?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not images, so people can copy/paste it into their own notebooks and experiment with possible solutions. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951). It would also help a lot if you could pintpoint exactly what the problem is, what code you used in your attempts, what the output was, and what you expected to obtain instead.

Comment: Look at [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

Comment: You get the imaginary part simply by: Im[...]. Or the real and imaginary part together by: ReIm[...]. Or the argument of the complex number by: Arg: